# Why can't I create an association with several fields?

Tags: c#, database, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to create this association but VS tells me that cannot be possible.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in your example, this would mean that: `Range1ID`, `Range2ID`, `Range3ID` and `Range4ID` all need to be equal (among themselves and to `RangeID`). If they are always equal, you don't need separate fields.